# What is the difference between a hard coded table and a look up table in SQL?

Tags: sql

Someone told me to avoid hard coding values in tables and to rather use look up tables. I'm not sure what the difference is. Can someone please explain?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Hi a lookup table is a normal table - in general you put information in there that is used repeatedly. You may or may not use ids for the values (often you do - integers are ideal for fast lookups, but short character codes can be more user-friendly).

Examples are:

### status_codes

| id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | pending |
| 2 | approved |
| 3 | denied |

### us_states

| abbreviation | name |
| --- | --- |
| AL | Alabama |
| AK | Alaska |
| AR | Arkansas |

The advantage of a lookup table are two-fold:

1. It easy to have two different values "hard-coded" two different way - a situation to be avoided at all costs!
2. it lets you "maintain" the table in a consistent way through regular updates and even through administration pages in you application.  If you hard code data into your queries and stored procedures - well, if anything changes you have to find all the places where values are hard-coded and change them in place.

In your question, the particular phrase *hard coded table* is somewhat ambiguous - perhaps it means creating a temp table in a query or stored procedure. The reasoning about it, with the pros and cons, is pretty much the same though - ease of use, consistency, and maintainability.

As with many things, it's probably not something that's always true all of the time. If you had a small "lookup table" that you really only have in one query and is highly unlikely to ever need to be updated or used in other queries - its not the end of the world to have it hard-coded in. But if the coding standards where you are dictate otherwise, its best to just go with the flow.

Comment: Would this be considered hard-coding? INSERT INTO dbo.Type (type ) VALUES('1'), ('2') and this look up: INSERT INTO Empty (col1, col2)
SELECT [Ticket Number], [Service Category]
FROM Correspondence;
?

Comment: hard to say ... everything about the answer to such a question depends on the data (what could or should be "looked up", vs. data that cannot be so)

Comment: I suppose in general lookups are used in joins, though. Usually they provide some datum that is used in conjunction with something else (a status code with an order that has a status, or a state name to put with an address that has a state abbreviation, to take my examples from above).